# I never played computer games in the past, but since last month I do

Tags: since

Does this sentence work?

> I never played computer games in the past, but since last month I do.

If it does, does it omit an implied part, which is

> (since last month) I have been playing and (I do)

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't omit the implied part.

Maybe something like this will work better:

> I have never played computer games in the past, but since the last month, I have been.

or

> I only just started playing computer games, since the last month.

EDIT: Kate's version is better. I completely forgot that the word "had" existed.

Comment: "I had never played computer games before, but a month ago I started doing so."

Comment: Does it work to say *since last month I do*?

Comment: You could get away with it in informal speech, but strictly speaking _since_ requires a past tense - _I have been doing so_.

Comment: -1 for incorrectly adding the definite article, "the", before "last month"